# elscreen on startup

Tags: elscreen

I installed elscreen through melpa & it works if I open the emacs and type `M-x elscreen-start`. **How to start the elscreen automatically?** `(require 'elscreen)` in .emacs does NOT automatically start the elscreen option.

Comment: **As to question number 1**:  How about putting `(require 'elscreen) (elscreen-start)` at the bottom of your `.emacs`?  *Or*, how about putting one of these hooks in your `.emacs` along with `(require 'elscreen)`?  `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'elscreen-start)` or `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'elscreen-start)`

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Let me suggest that you break this post up into two, discrete posts that ask a single question each.